# making an each in the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In movie_controller I added this

```
  def the_followers
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @followings = @movie.followings.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
                   .page(params[:page]).per(10)

    render layout: nil
  end
```

the_followers is the name of the file in view/movies/the_followers

in movie (view) I added this. but It did not work. Why?

```
<% @followings.each do |following| %>
  Username: <%= following.user.username %>
<% end %>
```

I have a blank list. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Did you check that `@followings` is not an empty array ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have different issues providing the list empty. Try following steps to isolate the problem.

remove scopes

```
@followings = Following.all.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 100)
```

Add them one by one

```
@followings = @movie.foollowings.all.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 100)
```

then try

```
@followings = @movie.foollowings.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).paginate(page: 1, per_page: 100)
```

finally

```
@followings = @movie.followings.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
                   .page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

See for yoursellf, at what step you'r array becomes empty.

Comment: Just noted that the issue is .where(user_id: params[:user_id])

Comment: what happens if i will remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simplest debugging method to locate the problem.

```
def the_followers
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  # Check movie followings array is empty?
  puts "---movie following num: #{@movie.followings.count}---"
  # Check the user_id param is present?
  puts "---user_id: #{params[:user_id]}---"
  # Check movie followings with user_id is empty?
  puts "---movie following with user_id num: #{@movie.followings.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).count}---"
  @followings = @movie.followings.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
               .page(params[:page]).per(10)
  # Check the result is empty?
  puts "---result num: #{@followings.count}---"
  render layout: nil
end
```

If all puts correct, then check the views code.

Comment: Just noted that the issue is .where(user_id: params[:user_id]), what happens if I remove it?

Comment: If you just show all followings about the movie, I think you can remove it. What about business logic of this?